# How do you handle shared members when dealing with interfaces?

Tags: vb.net, interface, static, properties, decoupling

So I did tons and tons of work trying to make an interface for a common set of classes.  The idea was to make an interface that each class could use within the set, but ultimately each class is different.  Turns out interfaces do not like shared members.  What I tried:

```
Public Interface ISomeInterface
Shared Property Meta() as Object
End Interface


Public Class A

Implements ISomeInterface
Shared Public Property Meta() as Object Implements ISomeInterFace.Meta
'Set/get methods
End Propery

Public Function Haduken() as Object
'perform Haduken
End Function
End Class


Public Class B

Implements ISomeInterface
Shared Public Property Meta() as Object Implements ISomeInterFace.Meta
'Set/get methods
End Propery

Public Function SonicBoom() as Object
'perform sonic boom
End Function
End Class
```

Obviously, had I done my homework on this, I would have known that shared members can't be use in interfaces.  Should I just leave the individual classes completely responsible for handling its shared members?  Is there another way to keep coupling down to a minimum with shared members?  Theres about 20 something or so classes that will implement a single interface.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to work around this is to have a `Private` implementation of the interface which simply forwards to the `Shared` member

```
Public Shared Property Meta As Object
  ' Get / Set methods
End Property

Private Property MetaImpl() as Object Implements ISomeInterFace.Meta
  Get 
    return Meta
  End Get
  Set
    Meta = Value
  End Set
End Propery
```

This pattern allows you to maintain the same public facing API and still implement the interface.

Comment: What would the Interface look like?

    Public Interface ISomeInterface 
    Private Property MetaImpl() as Object 
    End Interface

Comment: @hydroparadise the interface doesn't need to change at all for this pattern

Comment: Problem with this is that you need to then instantiate the derived class to access the shared member.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is that each implementation of the interface should use its own shared variable, JaredPar's approach is the right one.  If the idea is that all users of the interface should see the same shared variable, regardless of what instance they have (if any), the right approach is to create a class with a name similar to the interface, and use a shared member of that class.  That is the approach used by e.g. Enumerable<T>.Empty or Comparer<T>.Default.