# Force multiple classes to have a specific shared member

Tags: vb.net, class, interface, shared

I'm already searching for hours, but I cannot find any solution or even a possible way, that fits.
I need a way to enforce, that multiple classes have a shared member. This classes can not be inherits another class, because they are entity data model classes and i work on a partial class file beside the autogenerated files.

I tried to use an interface, but interfaces does not provide the option to declare a member as shared.

My try was like:

```
Public Interface IInterfaceA
    ReadOnly Property PropA as String
End Interface

Public Partial Class ClassA
    Implements IInterfaceA

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property SPropA As String
        Get
            Return "FixedValueStringForClassA"
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property PropA As String Implements IInterfaceA.PropA
        Get
            Return SPropA
        End Get
    End Property
End Class 

Public Partial Class ClassB
    Implements IInterfaceA

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property SPropA As String
        Get
            Return "FixedValueStringForClassB"
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property PropA As String Implements IInterfaceA.PropA
        Get
            Return SPropA
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

So I can call the `PropA` Member, when I get e.g. an array of types, that implements `IInterfaceA`.

But my first implementation does not enforce the shared property, only the normal property. To call the normal property, I would need an instance of that type, but this is not the way I searching for.

Maybe there is another solution to this problem.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613133/how-do-you-handle-shared-members-when-dealing-with-interfaces) with a couple of approaches :)

Comment: @AFriend the solution in the related question is the same as I wrote by myself. But this does not force the class to have this shared member. To have to remember every time (still in months and years, and by other developers) that the interface implemented member has to provide a shared member, that is not defined to be there by something, is (imho) not the way that I think is a good way.

Comment: By being shared, the only way to access it is by specifying the class name then the property ClassB.SPropA. You can't override a shared property. Why is this shared needed? How is it accessed? If it's with reflection, you could throw an exception. If not, it seems like it should just be a normal property.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not currently supported in .NET.  There is no way to require a class to provide a specific shared member.  The best you can do is use reflection to ensure that the item is there at runtime.  The usage you're showing, you don't really need a `Shared` member (it would be adequate to use an instance member), but there are certainly cases where the lack is felt: I've really missed it with factory patterns, where I can only enforce the existence of a shared construction method at runtime using reflection, and carefully document what is supposed to be present.

Comment: It is required, because I use the class types by itself as parameter for a task, that is registered at another program part, that runs that task and handles with objects in SQL. At the point where the parameters were registered the class types are seen only at runtime. So I need a way to ensure that this classes fulfill a convention, that they provide this shared member, that provides necessary information for the SQL statements.

Comment: @Craig Thanks for this answer. I also saw this dead end, but i hoped somebody knows another way. But I will finde some way to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't force a class to implement a shared member.
However, you CAN share extension methods from a module.

I had a similar problem recently with needing to share functions with multiple classes but still be able to run them as that class. Which I solved using extension methods.

Basically how it works is the module extends all objects that implement an interface, which can be conveniently included with the module, that interface will include anything the module will need access to from the calling class and the module will include anything that needs to be shared between all classes

```
Public Module SharedProp
    Dim PropA As String

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetPropA(Of T As IInterfaceA)(this As T) As String
        Return PropA
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Sub SetPropA(Of T As IInterfaceA)(this As T, value As String)
        PropA = value
    End Function

    Public Interface IInterfaceA
        Property PropA As String
    End Interface
End Module
```

so long as the module is included, any class which impliments your interface will have access to the module's extension methods, which in turn has access to the module's implicitly shared members

```
Imports SharedProp

Public Partial Class ClassA
    Implements IInterfaceA

    Public Property PropA As String Implements IInterfaceA.PropA
        Get
            Return Me.GetPropA()
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.SetPropA(value)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Partial Class ClassB
    Implements IInterfaceA

    Public Property PropA As String Implements IInterfaceA.PropA
        Get
            Return Me.GetPropA()
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.SetPropA(value)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Hope that helps solve your problem!

EDIT: Shared on Class basis instead of Interface

```
Public Module SharedProp
    Dim PropA As Dictionary(Of Type, String)

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetPropA(Of T As IInterfaceA)(this As T) As String
        If PropA.ContainsKey(GetType(T)) Then
            Return PropA(T)
        Else
            Return Nothing
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Sub SetPropA(Of T As IInterfaceA)(this As T, value As String) As String
        If PropA.ContainsKey(GetType(T) Then
            PropA(T) = value
        Else
            PropA.Add(GetType(T), value)
        End If
    End Function

    Public Interface IInterfaceA
        Property PropA As String
    End Interface
End Module
```

Comment: It looks like this limits the numbers of instances of all PropA to a single one. The single one, that is located in the module. Or did i miss something? And the extensions doesn't let me get access to the PropA without an object.

Comment: yes, this simply allows a property implemented by an interface to behave as though it is [Shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared) with all classes that use that interface.

if you want to share on all instances of a type, but not between types, see my edit.

as for needing to declare an object first, unfortunately there is no easy way around that. Not with VB anyways

Comment: I changed my way away from the Interface as main part. Now I use a MustInherit Class (that implement an empty interface, to get collections of different subclasses) with some MustOverrides and a Dictionary to separate the different shared variables of the subclasses  and wrote an extension for Type (with check for valid types, as subclasses of the MustInherit Class)  that provides a shared method to get the shared variable for that subclass. And now I can force PropA to be in every subclass, provide a shared and non-shared (same name) to access to the PropA, that is different for each subclass

Comment: Now I have the option for `ObjectOfSubclass.PropA` and also `GetType(Subclass).PropA`